# Loops in Loop Quantum Gravity

Tags: quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity, network

Am I correct in understanding that in [Loop Quantum Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity), loops are somehow interconnected with each other or interact, or is there some form of quantum entanglement between them? And if so, can we assume that there was no connection between loops before the appearance of space-time?

Answer (score 1):

In LQG, loops are not physical objects but mathematical symbols we use to label the states of quantum spacetime. They don't interact in the usual meaning of that word.

Comment: And what interacts? Space-time is not composed of interconnected elements?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян why do you want something to interact so badly? Again, loops are a system of labels we chose to use to denote the quantum states of spacetime. LQG is a theory of quantum spacetime, not interacting loops.

Comment: That is, space-time is something single and indivisible?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян I encourage you to read up on LQG. Currently your questions don’t make a lot of sense, unfortunately. I have no idea what you mean by “single” or “indivisible”, in general such epithets do not carry much meaning. LQG is a very specific mathematical model that will answer all of your conceptual questions way better than a metaphor would. Like with everything in physics, if you want to understand LQG, your best bet is to study the mathematics of it.